# Block token in DRF

Tags: django-rest-framework

Hello I have an application where the user access a login in and thereby obtains a token through an endpoint.

I want to block certain users according to their profile (which is linked to a company).

What I did was put my logic here:

```py
class CustomTokenAuthenticationView(ObtainAuthToken):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    ...
```

I can do it, but I wanted to do something more hard. In this case I wanted to block access to the token as a whole. What would be the best way?

Comment: Sounds like a custom permission check would be in order? https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#custom-permissions, https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#setting-the-permission-policy

Comment: It's an interesting way. Thank you